# Facebook 3.0 sdk 's ExecuteBatchAndWait method returns empty response

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to execute multiple requests at the "executeBatchAndWait" method. I am expecting the function to return only after all requests have been executed and all response received. But, the function returns instantly. And when I do,

```
response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
```

It throws a null pointer exception.

**CODE:**

```
Log.v(TAG, "executing album requests");
List<Response> mResponsesList = Request.executeBatchAndWait(mAlbumPhotosRequests);
Log.v(TAG, "received album responses");
```

**OUTPUT**

02-13 15:48:45.900: executing album requests

02-13 15:48:45.904: received album responses

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any error in your response before accessing the JSON Object.

response.getError()

It may be the reason why the GraphObject is not created

Comment: I would 1. try one request at a time 2. check the responses in the Graph Explorer tool - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, you can use your access token there or make sure the default access token has the required permissions

Comment: I am using executeBatchAsync() for now and it works perfectly, but while waiting for response (for all requests) using requestAsyncTask.get(); I have to wait on the UI thread which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: You can start your own async task, request for batch in the background & then in postprocess update the UI. Till then show a loading/wait screen probably

Comment: I have tried this. It exits doInBackground() immediately and in PostExecute() gives NullPointerException for the response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

Comment: Try using this when you before you setup your Facebook session
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_RAW_RESPONSES);
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);

This should dump what is exactly happening when the requests are made

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an empty response.
This is a scenario usually related with running simultaneous FB requests on your own threads.
I learnt the hard way to use either

```
Request.executeAsync()
```

or

```
RequestAsyncTask
```